# Remove double quotes from output Java

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to extract a url from the string. But I am unable to skip the double quotes in the output.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1 = "<a id=\"BUTTON_LINK\" style=\"%%BUTTON_LINK%%\" target=\"_blank\" href=\"https://||domainName||/basketReviewPageLoadAction.do\">%%CHECKOUT%%</a>";
    //System.out.println(s1);
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s*(?i)href\\s*=\\s*(\"([^\"]*\")|'[^']*'|([^'\">\\s]+))");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s1);

    if(matcher.find()){
      String url = matcher.group(1);
      System.out.println(url);
    }

  }
}
```

My Output is:

```
"https://||domainName||/basketReviewPageLoadAction.do"
```

Expected Output is:

```
https://||domainName||/basketReviewPageLoadAction.do
```

I cannot do string replace. I have add few get param in this output and attach back it to original string.

Comment: After if statement use `url.replaceAll(" \" ","");` as a statement

Comment: I don't wish to replace because I need that url again to be attached to original string after adding few params.`https://||domainName||/basketReviewPageLoadAction.do?abc=12`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Regex**: [`(?<=href=")([^\"]*)`](https://regex101.com/r/DihDZj/1) **Substitution**: `$1?params...`

**Details**:

- `(?<=)` Positive Lookbehind
- `()` Capturing group
- `[^]` Match a single character not present in the list
- `*` Matches between zero and unlimited times
- `$1` Group 1.

**Java code**:

By using function `replaceAll` you can add your params `?abc=12` to the end of the capturing group `$1` in this case `href`.

```
String text = "<a id=\"BUTTON_LINK\" style=\"%%BUTTON_LINK%%\" target=\"_blank\" href=\"https://||domainName||/basketReviewPageLoadAction.do\">%%CHECKOUT%%</a>";
text = text.replaceAll("(?<=href=\")([^\"]*)", String.format("$1%s", "?abc=12"));
System.out.print(text);
```

**Output**:

```
<a id="BUTTON_LINK" style="%%BUTTON_LINK%%" target="_blank" href="https://||domainName||/basketReviewPageLoadAction.do?abc=12">%%CHECKOUT%%</a>
```

[Code demo](http://rextester.com/SLT89635)

Comment: This is Perfect!! I exactly needed this. Thank you.

Comment: @Abhishek I don't understand how does that help you? Didn't you want this ouput: `https://||domainName||/basketReviewPageLoadAction.do`?

Comment: @Eugene S "I need that url again to be attached to original string after adding few params.". Read all of his comments.

Comment: @EugeneS what I posted was a part of the final task. I wanted to extract the url and add some get Params in it and add that url back to the href tag template

Comment: @Abhishek Edit your post.

Answer (score 1):

You can try one of these options:

```
System.out.println(url.replaceAll("^\"|\"$", ""));
System.out.println(url.substring(1, url.length()-1));
```

Answer (score 0):

ugly, seems works.Hope this help.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = "<a id=\"BUTTON_LINK\" style=\"%%BUTTON_LINK%%\" target=\"_blank\" href= \"https://||domainName||/basketReviewPageLoadAction.do\">%%CHECKOUT%%</a>";
        //System.out.println(s1);
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s*(?i)href\\s*=\\s*(\"([^\"]*)\"|'([^']*)'|([^'\">\\s]+))");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s1);

        if (matcher.find()) {
            String url = Stream.of(matcher.group(2), matcher.group(3),
                    matcher.group(4)).filter(s -> s != null).collect(Collectors.joining());
            System.out.print(url);

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for now.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s*(?i)href\\s*=\\s*\"([^\"]*)");
```

Comment: how about "href ='https://||domainName||/basketReviewPageLoadAction.do' ", I see your pattern posted in the question want to handle situation like this.

Answer (score -1):

You will try this out,

```
s1 = s1.Replace("\"", "");
```